# MSSQL Most optimal query for date range for a day, or day range

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, range

I wanted to find out what is the "best practices" approach to a query against a record set of datetime with a date (no time).

I use several queries that return records based on a date range, from a recordset that uses a datetime data type, which means each record needs to be checked using a between range.

Example of a query would be:

```
Select * 
FROM Usages 
where CreationDateTime between '1/1/2012' AND '1/2/2012 11:59:59'
```

I know using `BETWEEN` is a resource hog, and that checking a datetime data type of a date is always going to be very resource intense, but I would like to hear what others use (or would use) in this situation.

Would I get any type of performance increase converting the datetime record to a Date  like:

```
Select * 
FROM Usages 
where CONVERT(DATE,CreationDateTime) between '1/1/2012' AND '1/2/2012'
```

Or possibly doing a check of less then / greater then?

```
Select * 
FROM Usages 
where (CreationDateTime > '1/1/2012') 
    AND (CreationDateTime < '1/2/2012 11:59:59')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you think you know is not correct.

Neither using `BETWEEN` or DATETIME data types is a resource hog.

Provided that you index the column, that the column really is a DATETIME and not a VARCHAR(), and that you don't wrap the field in a function, everything will be nice and quick.

That said, I would use `>=` and `<` instead. Not for performance, but logical   correctness.

```
WHERE
  myField >= '20120101'
  AND myField < '20120102'
```

This will work no matter whether the field contains hours, minutes, or even (with a mythical data type) pico seconds.

With an index on the field it will also give a range scan.

You won't get any faster.  No tricks or functions needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I didn't realize using 20120201 instead of 02/01/2012 works in such a way, and thanks for confirming the best approach to dealing with these types of queries.

Comment: @eric - The benefit of `'20120201T00:00:00.000'` is that it is not language dependant *(it's always interpretted as 'YYYYMMDD' for the date part)*.  Where as `'02/01/2012'` can be either 1st Feb or 2nd Jan, depending on where you come from.

Answer (score 1):

There are several considerations regarding dates.

First, you want to be sure that relevant indexes get used.  In general, this means avoiding functions on the column.  This applies to data types other than dates, but functions a prevalant for understanding dates.  So, CONVERT() is a bad idea from a performance perspective, assuming that the column is indexed.

Second, you want to avoid unnecessary conversions between formats.  So, a call to a function must happen for every row.  Instead, converting a constant string to a date/time happens once at compile time.  The first is less efficient.  Another reason to avoid CONVERT().  However, in many queries, other processing (such as joins) is far more time-consuming than conversions, so this may not be important.

As for the choice between "between" and signed operations.  The better practice is to use "<" and ">" and ">=" and "<=".  It makes the logic clearer for dates and doesn't have an issue with things like seconds being accurate to 3 ms.

As far as I know, between on dates works as efficiently using indexes as other types of fields.  However, for accuracy and portability it is best to do the individual comparisons.

So, the third version would be preferred.

Comment: For continuous variable (rather than discrete variables) it should be `>= AND <` rather than `> AND <`.  Also, the consideration to using functions *(including `CONVERT()`)* is not the cost of the operation, it's that it obfuscates the index - and so is processed individually on every row rather than being used to generate a range scan quickly.

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback.  I generally try to never use functions unless needed (generally handle converting data after fetch).  Oh and yeah I do use >= and <= with queries, I simply forget to include the euqals to in attempting to keep my posts/examples as small as possible.